# Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, and let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be linear. Then T is one-to-one if and only if $N(T) = {0 }$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So yeah, title has the theorem I need to prove. In Freidburg, it is given as follows:

> . Suppose that $T$ is one-to-one and $x \in N(T)$. Then $T(x) = 0 =
> T(0 )$. Since $T$ is one-to-one, we have $x = 0$ . Hence $N(T) = {0 }$.

However how they just wrote following $T(x) = 0 =
T(0 )$, I mean if we are writing $T(x)=0$, $x$ can be anything, or $x \in V$ such that $T(x)=0$, why it is specifically that $x=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming $N(T)$ means the null space or kernel of $T$.)

The point is that $T$ is one-to-one. Since $T(x)=0$ and $T(0)=0$, we must have $x=0$. This is just from the definition of injectivity: if $T(x)=T(y)$, then $x=y$.

Comment: But how you wrote $T(0)=0$?

Comment: We know $T(0)=0$ since $T$ is a linear map. If $T$ is injective and $T(x)=0$, then since $0$ and $x$ both map to the same thing, they must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

$N(T)$ is the kernel or null space of the linear transformation $T$.

The kernel of a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ is defined as the set of all vector $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=0$, where $0$ is the zero vector in $W$.

Now, $T(0)=0$, since
$$
T(0) = T(0 + 0) = T(0) + T(0) \\
\implies T(0)=0
$$

Since $T$ is one-one, only one vector can be mapped to $0\in W$, this must $0\in V$. Thus the kernel of T, $N(T)$ contains only one element, namely $0\in V$.